# C# Web API 2 - Ignore file uploads with different field name

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2, multipartform-data

I am able now to accept files from the client using MultipartFormDataStreamProvider class which i get [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2)
and able to rename the files according to the file name.

The thing is, i want to ignore the field in form data that is not what i want.

For example i want only a field in form data with a fieldname of ***profilePic*** and the rest of other field will be ignored.

The problem is, the files that is not what i am expecting is being saved in the server.

I want to delete those files. How can i do that?

Here's my code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/topher/upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, new { message = "Set the content-type of header to multipart/form-data" });
    }

    string rootFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MyStreamProvider(rootFolder);

    try
    {
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

        foreach (var key in streamProvider.FormData.AllKeys)
        {
            // the key is where the formdata keys is saved
            // but the key of the file is not in here
        }

        foreach (MultipartFileData file in streamProvider.FileData)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
            Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName); 
            // This is where the filepath of the files
            // I want to delete the file that the key in the form-data is not profilePic
        }

    return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Ok(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will update my example. Thanks

Comment: Please share how you are passing files to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the field name in the form using `file.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name`

```
<input name="profilePic" type="file" />
```

in `foreach` you can check as below

```
if (file.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "profilePic")
{
   // delete the file
}
```

Comment: Good catch bro. This is what i am looking for. 

Now i can delete files that are uploaded that have not a field name of ```profilePic```